# Which dyadic rationals can be built on domineering boards?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

In the game of domineering, exactly as defined in Winning Ways, is it possible to build any number of the form $\frac{a}{2^b}, a\in\mathbb{Z}, b\in\mathbb{N}$? Is there an pragmatic/algorithmic way of instancing such numbers?

I was able to find 0, $\pm\frac{1}{2}$,$\pm\frac{1}{4}$,$\pm\frac{3}{4}$, in several different ways. When trying to extend previos boards by following a pattern I came up with I always end up in one of the previous calculated cases again. When I mix in squares in arbitrary positions, I end up getting non-numbers. In case it is not possible to build all such numbers, what dyadics can one build?

I am using CGSuite to calculate the examples I build. In case it helps: When trying to get to $\frac{7}{8}$, for example, I tried the following cases:

##.|##.|...|.## = 3/4

.##|.##|...|##.|...|.## = 3/4

.##|.##|...|##.|##.|...|.## = 3/4

####.|####.|##...|##.##|...##|.#### = 3/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them.

In the 2015 [Theoretical Computer Science](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/theoretical-computer-science) paper "[New results for Domineering from combinatorial game theory endgame databases](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397515004211)" ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03949)) by Uiterwijk and Barton, a construction is provided to produce any dyadic rational in a (connected!) board of Domineering.

They cite the 1996 paper [New values in Domineering](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397595001506) by Yonghoan Kim, which showed a construction for connected boards of value $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Hi, sorry to come back to this question. I believe I am missing something from the 2015 paper you linked. I would like to know if Kim's snakes always have "explosive" squares. I thought of a way of proving it using the theorems the paper mentions, because there are isolated cases of explosive squares. My questions is if the existence of explosive squares is even more trivial than that. How would you ensure there will always be these squares?

Comment: @MTLaurentys I'm not sure what you're asking here. "if Kim's snakes always have "explosive" squares": I don't think Kim's snakes as in Figure 10 have *any* explosive squares. We add explosive squares to it as in Fig. 11 and Fig. 13. "How would you ensure there will always be these squares?" The paper explicitly added them to Kim's snakes to build things like Fig. 14.

Comment: My bad. By "having explosive squares" I meant to write "explosive squares can always be added to snakes" . My question should have been "How would you ensure that you can always add explosive squares to the snakes?"

Comment: @MTLaurentys They show in Figs 11 and 13 exactly where the squares should go at the beginning of a Fig 10-style snake. You can always put them in the same place because any snake for a value of $1/16$ or less contains the left snake of Fig 11 and then proceeds up and to the right as in Fig 10 (so it won't get in the way of these squares). These squares are indeed explosive: The first is because a move on it (necessarily by Left) is the same as Left moving one square higher. The second is because moving on it is dominated by Left moving one square higher.